# Auto expand child when parent checked on treelist using javascript

Tags: javascript, treelist, radtreelist

Can someone teach me how to expand child item on tree list when parent item was checked in JavaScript?

Current,i had  function on JavaScript to check/unchecked parent item and child item. But this function fail to auto expand the child item when parent item was checked. Can someone lead me a hand please?

Here is my JavaScript.

```js
  var parenItemSelected = false;
        function OnClientNodeClicked(sender, args) {
            var currNode = args.get_item();
            var childNodes = currNode.get_childItems();
            var nodeCount = currNode.get_childItems().length;
            var parentItem = currNode.get_parentItem();

            if (parentItem) {

                parenItemSelected = true;
                parentItem.set_selected(true);
            }

            if (currNode.get_selected()) {
                CheckAllChildren(childNodes, nodeCount);
            }
            else {
                UnCheckAllChildren(currNode, childNodes, nodeCount);
            }
            parenItemSelected = false;
        }

        function UnCheckAllChildren(currNode, nodes, nodecount) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < nodecount; i++) {
                nodes[i].set_selected(false);
            }
            currNode.set_selected(false);
        }

        function CheckAllChildren(nodes, nodecount) {
            var i;

            if (!parenItemSelected) {
                for (i = 0; i < nodecount; i++) {
                    nodes[i].set_selected(true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Code from C# or vb.net are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: which tree plugin are you using ?

Comment: radtreelist from telerik

Comment: if using normal treelist from visual studio, anyone know the solution?